# Calculating the index of moderated moderated mediation with multicategorical and dichotomous moderators

Tags: interaction, mediation

I am conducting a moderated moderated mediation analysis using Hayes' PROCESS macro for SAS. I have a multicategorical independent variable (i.e, three levels of X), a continuous mediator (M) and two moderators (W and Z), one multicategorical (i.e, three levels of W) and one dichotomous.

I can perform the analysis and get the conditional indirect effects of my explanatory variable for each combination of the moderators.  However, the program does not provide the index of moderated moderated mediation given the multicategorical moderator (this was confirmed).  I believe I understand that the index of moderated moderated mediation ([Hayes 2017](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03637751.2017.1352100)) is generally the product of the coefficient of the three-way interaction of X, W, and Z in the first stage analysis of M and the effect of the mediator in the second stage, and can be tested with a bootstrap confidence interval.

However, with two 3-level moderators, there are four interactions terms in the first stage regression examining M.  In this case, how are the index of moderated moderated mediation and the bootstrap confidence interval calculated?